# Why isn't this question about a hypothetical scenario considered off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I recently received [this Low Quality audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7592648) that was asking how "return-to-libc attacks could be performed if the attacker has no access to registers."

I recommended closing it since there was no specific question related to programming, and I felt it would be a much better fit on Stack Exchange site *[Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour)* (as the [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security) tag recommends) or 
perhaps Stack Exchange site *[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)* since it's hypothetical. At the very least, the question should be edited to improve readability. However, I failed the audit, as the correct response was "Looks OK."

I was under the impression that there needed to be a question about a specific problem that a user is having in order for the question to be considered on-topic, so why is this question okay?

Comment: That question has three upvotes, two favourites, an answer with a score of 1, and no close votes. From a machine's point of view there's nothing to indicate that it's *not* a good question.

Comment: Likes and favs  do not save from being off-topic. Feel it.

Comment: @Joker That's not what I'm saying at all. Audit questions aren't hand-picked by people, they're randomly picked by code, and the fact that the actions on that question have been mostly *positive* means the code has no reason to think it's a bad question. Basically, it seems like it's considered a good question by the audit because nobody has taken action to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Bad audits happen. If you've been review-banned, contact a moderator to have the ban removed (what normally happens in this situation).